# How do I prevent a bluetooth headset from muting when it hears sound

Tags: bluetooth, mute

I have a Plantronics M50 headset, which works wonderfully on my Android 4.0.4 Sony Xperia Ion LT28at.  However, it mutes its output anytime it detects a loud enough sound.  If I type during a business call the incoming signal becomes choppy, and high wind sometimes causes callers to disappear completely for seconds at a time.

I have no other headset to test whether this is due to Android or the device, though I have tested with another Plantronics M50 with the same result.  I assume the headset is a simple receiver/transmitter, and so assume that this is probably a setting in Android, but I don't know for sure.

How do I turn this feature off?  How do I cause my bluetooth speaker to continue outputting regardless of what its microphone picks up?